# Unresolved reference: KotlinCompilerVersion in build.gradle.kts

Tags: kotlin, build.gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

In `build.gradle.kts` file, I include this code on the top line. Then I use KotlinCompilerVesion.VERSION below.

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.config.KotlinCompilerVersion
```

Some code works fine, but some code failed:

It seems like only `plugins` block can not enable this `import`.

Here works fine:

```
dependencies {
    Implementation(kotlin("stdlib-jdk7", KotlinCompilerVersion.VERSION))
    Implementation(kotlin("test", KotlinCompilerVersion.VERSION))
}
```

Here always wrong:

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    kotlin("android")
    kotlin("android.extensions")

    /*
    * Error: Unresolved reference: KotlinCompilerVersion
    */
    id("kotlinx-serialization") version KotlinCompilerVersion.VERSION

    /*
    * Error: Unresolved reference: KotlinCompilerVersion
    */
    id("kotlinx-serialization") version "$KotlinCompilerVersion.VERSION"

    /*
    * Error: Unresolved reference: KotlinCompilerVersion
    */
    id("kotlinx-serialization") version "${KotlinCompilerVersion.VERSION}"
}
```

How can I use it correctly in here, without declare an `ext.xxxVersion` var?

Comment: I tried it and `plugins` scope seems very strict, You can still use fully qualified name to reference the value, even bind it to a variable inside it but any import seems to be ignored. You actually get an odd warning if You try to set `val` to VERSION outside the scope and try to reference it inside.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, the syntax of the plugins DSL is limited because Gradle parses it **before** parsing the rest of the file, which requires the definition to be static (no references to variables, constants, etc., pretty much no code is allowed). See [Limitations of the plugins DSL](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#plugins_dsl_limitations) for details.

The way I handle defining Kotlin version only once is by actually using the version I specify in the plugins block as canonical in other sections of the file (I picked this up from [this blog post by Simon Wirtz](http://kotlinexpertise.com/gradlekotlindsl/)) like so:

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.KotlinPluginWrapper

val kotlinVersion = plugins.getPlugin(KotlinPluginWrapper::class.java)
        .kotlinPluginVersion

plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.3.30"
}

dependencies {
    implementation(platform(kotlin("bom", kotlinVersion)))
    implementation(kotlin("stdlib-jdk8"))
}
```

But yeah, in the plugins block it needs to be static and unfortunately repeated if needed.

---

**Update**: I actually just learned it's possible to use constants in the plugins DSL, but they must be defined before Gradle parses the `build.gradle.kts` file, i.e. from `buildSrc`. I noticed this in the [fuel](https://github.com/kittinunf/fuel) library. In essence, create `buildSrc/build.gradle.kts` with the following contents:

```
plugins {
    `kotlin-dsl`
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
}
```

Then create `buildSrc/src/main/kotlin/Constants.kt` with the following contents:

```
object Kotlin {
    const val version = "1.3.30"
}
```

And then you'll be able to use the following in your main `build.gradle.kts`:

```
plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version Kotlin.version
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Local variable in plugin block

One solution is to define a local object in the `plugin {}` block. This can reduce duplication within the block itself.

```
    plugins {
val PluginVersions =
    object {
        val SPRING_BOOT = "3.2.2"
        val SPRING_DEPENDENCY_MANAGEMENT = "1.1.4"
        val KOTLIN = "1.9.22"
        val KTFMT = "0.17.0"
    }

war
id("org.springframework.boot") version PluginVersions.SPRING_BOOT
id("io.spring.dependency-management") version PluginVersions.SPRING_DEPENDENCY_MANAGEMENT
kotlin("jvm") version PluginVersions.KOTLIN
kotlin("plugin.spring") version PluginVersions.KOTLIN
kotlin("plugin.serialization") version PluginVersions.KOTLIN
id("com.ncorti.ktfmt.gradle") version PluginVersions.KTFMT
```

}

### Gradle version catalog

You can also use the [Gradle version catalog](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/platforms.html) which lets you make a `gradle/libs.versions.toml` file which can be referenced from your `build.gradle.kts` file. It seems to be best practice for version management (especially if you share versions across multiple Gradle projects). However, personally I feel it makes the `build.gradle.kts` look like ugly with an overload of references and aliases everywhere.

### buildSrc folder

The contents of the buildSrc are available inside the `plugin {}` block. So if you add a basic `buildSrc/build.gradle.kts` folder with:

```
repositories { mavenCentral() }

plugins { `kotlin-dsl` }
```

And a `buildSrc/main/kotlin/Versions.kt` file with:

```
object Versions {
    const val SPRING = "3.2.2"
    const val SPRING_DEPENDENCY_MANAGEMENT = "1.1.4"
    const val KOTLIN = "1.9.22"
}
```

You will be able to access the object inside the `plugins {}` block.